# Visual Studio 2005 Output file requires Administrative Privileges

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Source Safe 2005, I downloaded a jobmate's project in my computer and built it correctly, but when I press "play" to debug it I receive an error message telling me that I need higher privileges.

Looking around, I've noticed that the freshly build program has the little shield icon that means that I need administrator permission to run it and actually, if I run it outside Visual Studio, I manage to execute it after the UAC question.

I'm domain and local administrator so I can disable UAC, but I don't think this is the solution, so: what can make my program to require administrative privileges?

Comment: Right-click the Visual Studio icon and select Run as Administror.

Comment: Well, WHY my output file needs administrative privileges?

Comment: It could be because of a variety of reasons. The program is accessing something (registry, folder location, etc.) that required elevated privileges. You can find out exactly what by running the App Compat Toolkit. It's part of the AIK, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753

Comment: Well, I have other applications that use registry, folders and so on, but I've never experiened such problem.